# Parsing html string from the element having no specific id and more than one class using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, find

I want to find a string from parsed html data, string is present in a div which has no specific id, but has more than one classes inherited to it.

below is my foo.html code and ajax jquery function.

foo.html

```
<div align="center">
   <div id="recaptchaDiv"></div>
   <div class="alert alert-block alert-error fade in">Incorrect Email or Password</div> 
</div>
```

ajax code

```
       $.ajax({
                    /*1*/url:"foo.html",    

                    /*2*/type: "POST",

                    /*3*/data: ({

                         username: usernm,
                         password: pass,
                         return_url: 'index.html',

                    }),

                    /*4*/dataType : "html",

                    /*5*/success : function(data, textStatus, response)
                    {
                        var recapcha = $(data).find(".alert-block").text();
                        console.log(recapcha);
                    }

             });
```

I want to find the text 'Incorrect Email or Password' from div.

Comment: is the variable `data` containing the raw HTML?

Comment: if you do a `console.log($(data));` what does it print?

Comment: it prints the complete html page that I've received from the server.

Comment: hmm, could you put the `console.log(data);` output into a [http://pastebin.com/](http://pastebin.com/) and show it to me ? This is really strange, it should work.

Comment: For that I'll have to disclose data from a product which hasn't been launched yet. Can't do that sorry.. :/

Comment: Is the page static or generated dynamically? I see that you are making a `POST` request and sending a user and pass as params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your block of html is unique in the DOM, use

`$('.alert-error').text()`

Edit1 - remove align

Comment: `.center` is not a class but an align value

Comment: so shall I remove find too function too?

Comment: Yes, you can remove `find`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in many ways:

```
 1) $("div[aligh='center'] div.alert-block").text();
 2) $("#recaptchaDiv").next().text();
 3) $(".alert.alert-block").text();
```

and so on...in different ways